# Microsoft SQL Server : converting 3 rows to 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, rows

I have a rather large report I am working on and as it turns out I need to have insurance information in 1 row rather than up to 3. I can get by on SQL coding with the basics but when it comes to pivot tables and other advanced tasks I bog down and it gets confusing, so I figured I would turn to you guys. I looked at several examples of changing rows to columns and started to understand it but when it came to the actually coding it started to turn into a mess. :(

**ISSUE**:
Trying to get all 3 insurances in one row rather than print a new row for each insurance with all the duplicate patient data.

```
EXAMPLE
TYPE  ACCTNUM_2    PaySrc_1   
2     000001       MEDICARE
2     000001       BLUE CROSS
2     000152       BLUE CROSS

I would like to display it as 
TYPE  ACCTNUM_2 ... PaySrc_1    PaySrc_2    PaySrc3
2     000001        MEDICARE    BLUE CROSS
2     000152        BLUE CROSS
```

CODE:

```
DECLARE
    @StartDate DateTime,
    @EndDate DateTime,
    SET @StartDate = '10/28/2013 00:00:000'
    SET @EndDate = '10/28/2013 23:59:000'
    SET @RecordType = '2'

SELECT 
    @RecordType AS RecordType
    ,ISNULL(AbstractData.AccountNumber,'') AS AcctNum
    ,ISNULL(AbsInsurances.InsuranceName,'') AS PaySrc_1
FROM AbstractData  
    JOIN AbsInsurances
        ON (AbsInsurances.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID)
        AND (AbsInsurances.SourceID = AbstractData.SourceID)


WHERE AbstractData.DischargeDateTime BETWEEN '05/15/2012 00:00:000' and '08/15/2012 00:00:000'
ORDER BY AbstractData.DischargeDateTime,
AbstractData.PatientID
```

Comment: Dont you mean column to rows?

Comment: If you have something to take their place I would gladly remove them. As it is now if I remove those two fields column 12 & 13 are removed and as noted I need all three insurances listed for the patient in the columns PaySrc 12, 13 and 14.

Comment: Your example is strange, you have values in column `PaySrc_12` and want to distribute them in the three columns 12 to 14?

Comment: No.. rows to columns. Im getting separate rows for each new ins. All the other data stays the same right now (I don't want that), I want all the insurances listed with all the patient data on one row, not three rows.

Comment: God I hate the parsing on this! It's hell trying to post columned data... :(

Comment: Yeah the parsing for the examples came out goofy, now it prints as follows______________________ AcctNum_2... ...PaySrc_12____PaySrc_13____PaySrc_14___________________________________________ 00000001_____MEDICARE___NULL__________NULL _________________________________________ 
00000001_____BLUE CROSS ____NULL___________ NULL _________________________________________________
    I want it to print like this:
00000001_____MEDICARE __BLUE CROSS___NULL

Comment: That qualifies as a true WTF SQL query, you are using SQL as a programing tool, it's a data persistence system. I pity the next programmer that has to maintain that! The shape of the query should have no relevance to the shape of the output, they should be two separate systems

Comment: Should be but their not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sub-queries worked fine and displayed the data as needed, across:

```
,(SELECT ISNULL(AI.InsuranceName,'')
    FROM AbsInsurances AI
    WHERE AI.InsuranceSeqID ='1' AND (AI.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID))
    AS PaySrc_12
,(SELECT ISNULL(AI.InsuranceName,'')
    FROM AbsInsurances AI
    WHERE AI.InsuranceSeqID ='2' AND (AI.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID))
    AS PaySrc_13
,(SELECT ISNULL(AI.InsuranceName,'')
    FROM AbsInsurances AI
    WHERE AI.InsuranceSeqID ='3' AND (AI.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID))
    AS PaySrc_14
```

Thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the explanation and the sample code, it is difficult to understand why you would want to try and do this in T-SQL. If there is a reporting tool that you can use, please try to use that instead.

There is a way to concatenate the list of names, but you will have to sacrifice your proposed report structure (slightly). Consider concatenating the values in `AbsInsurances.PaySrc_12`. Here is a snippet that you may be able to get working for you. If you do get it working, I strongly recommend that you use it as a temporary solution until you can find a more practical/maintainable method.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACCTNUM_2, STUFF(InsuranceProviders.Names, 1, 1, '') PAYSRC_12 
FROM AbstractData t
       CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT ',' + PaySrc_12 
                    FROM AbstractData
                    WHERE ACCTNUM_2 = t.ACCTNUM_2
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    )InsuranceProviders(Names) 
    WHERE ACCTNUM_2='000001'
```

Comment: Thanks rcjames. I ended up using the following code and it worked

    (SELECT ISNULL(AI.InsuranceName,'')
        FROM AbsInsurances AI
        WHERE AI.InsuranceSeqID ='1' AND (AI.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID))
        AS PaySrc_12
    ,(SELECT ISNULL(AI.InsuranceName,'')
        FROM AbsInsurances AI
        WHERE AI.InsuranceSeqID ='2' AND (AI.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID))
        AS PaySrc_13
    ,(SELECT ISNULL(AI.InsuranceName,'')
        FROM AbsInsurances AI
        WHERE AI.InsuranceSeqID ='3' AND (AI.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID))
        AS PaySrc_14